# LeetCode 665: Non-decreasing Array (C)

Tags: performance, beginner, algorithm, c, programming-challenge

I'm posting a solution for LeetCode's "Non-decreasing Array". If you'd like to review, please do. Thank you!

#### [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/non-decreasing-array/)

Given an array `nums` with `n` integers, your task is to check if it could become non-decreasing by modifying at most 1 element.

We define an array is non-decreasing if `nums[i] <= nums[i + 1]` holds for every i (0-based) such that (`0 <= i <= n - 2`).

#### Example 1:

- Input: nums = [4,2,3]
- Output: true
- Explanation: You could modify the first 4 to 1 to get a non-decreasing array.

#### Example 2:

- Input: nums = [4,2,1]
- Output: false
- Explanation: You can't get a non-decreasing array by modify at most one element.

#### Constraints:

- `1 <= n <= 10 ^ 4`
- `-10 ^ 5 <= nums[i] <= 10 ^ 5`

#### Code

```
// Since the relevant headers are already included on the LeetCode platform,
// the headers can be removed;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static const bool checkPossibility(
    int *nums,
    const int nums_size
) {

    if (nums_size < 3) {
        return true;
    }

    int max_changes = 0;

    for (int index = 1; index < nums_size - 1; ++index) {
        if (!(nums[index] >= nums[index - 1] && nums[index + 1] >= nums[index])) {
            if (nums[index + 1] >= nums[index - 1]) {
                ++max_changes;
                nums[index] = nums[index - 1];

            } else {
                if (nums[index] < nums[index - 1] && nums[index + 1] < nums[index]) {
                    return false;

                } else if (nums[index] <= nums[index + 1]) {
                    nums[index - 1] = nums[index];

                    if (!(index - 1) || nums[index - 2] <= nums[index - 1]) {
                        ++max_changes;

                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                } else {
                    nums[index + 1] = nums[index];
                    ++max_changes;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    return max_changes < 2;
}

int main() {

    static const int nums_size = 3;
    int nums_array[nums_size] = {4, 2, 1};
    int (*nums)[nums_size] = &nums_array;

    fputs(checkPossibility(*nums, nums_size) ? "true" : "false", stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplify the logic

Why does this solution look more complicated than the [C++ version you posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251617/leetcode-665-non-decreasing-array#251617)? It seems like you can use exactly the same logic as in the C++ version.

## Don't return `const` values

Declaring the return value to be `const` is not doing anything unless you return a pointer.

## Avoid unnecessary special case handling

You exit early if the size of the array is less than 3, but this is unnecessary: the rest of the code already handles arrays of size 0, 1 and 2 correctly. You might save a cycle if you feed it a small array, but you pay for this check with a cycle or two for every time the function is called with `nums_size > 2`.

## Simplify your `main()`

You do a lot of unnecessary things in `main()`:

- There's no need to have a constant for the array up front, as you can use `sizeof` to get the size of the array, and divide it by the size of one element to get the number of elements.
- There is no need to declare a pointer to the array, the array itself can be used as a pointer.
- `puts()` is like `fputs()`, but always writes to `stdout`, and adds a newline for you.
- The `return 0` is not necessary in `main()`.

So you can simplify it as follows:

```
int main() {
    int array[] = {4, 2, 1};
    puts(checkPossibility(array, sizeof array / sizeof *array) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**The code mutates an array**. It is not good.

**The code does too much**. You may `return false` as soon as `max_changes` reaches 2 (no need to examine the rest).

**More functions please**. It is very hard to follow the complicated decision making. Consider

```
int find_first_violation(int * nums, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < size; i++) {
        if (nums[i] < nums[i-1]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Then the business logic would be:

```
    int violation = find_first_violation(nums, size);

    if (violation == size) {
        // array is already non-decreasing
        return true;
    }
    if (violation == size - 1) {
        // easily fixable: increase nums[size - 1]
        return true;
    }

    // Now fix the violation
    // violation == 1 is fixable by decreasing nums[0]. No action needed.
    // Otherwise, we only care about the case where nums[violation] is too
    // small - less than two preceding numbers. It is only fixable by
    // increasing it, effectively setting it equal to nums[violation - 1].

    if ((violation > 1) && (nums[violation] < nums[violation - 2])) {
        nums[violation] = nums[violation - 1];
    }

    // Finally, the core argument to have more functions: there
    // must be no more violations.

    return find_first_violation(nums + violation, size - violation) == size - violation;
```

Of course the first two conditions can be combined into `violation >= size - 1`. Of course increasing of `nums[violation]` can be virtual, without mutating the array (if `nums[violation - 1] > nums[violation + 1]` we may immediately `return false;`).